# How to pass a COM pointer to every thread in a group of waiting background threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, com

Let's say you've obtained an `IShellItemArray` object, and you'd like to pass it as an argument (or otherwise make it available) to every thread in a group of waiting background threads. And also let's say that on each background thread, you actually have a C++ class, and the C++ class has a method that does stuff with the `IShellItemArray`.

In a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68960453/15284017), I learned that to pass an `IShellItemArray` pointer for use on background threads, you should marshal the pointer using a function like `RoGetAgileReference`, and then access the object from the background threads using `IAgileReference::Resolve`.

My current question is, more specifically, how to pass the interface pointer, or otherwise make it available, to every class/thread in the group of background threads.  Or I suppose I have two related questions:

1. **Which WinApi thread functions are most suitable for setting up the background threads?**
2. **How should the COM object pointer get passed to them?**

For example, let's say that each thread is in a wait-state using `WaitForSingleObject`, and it also has an  associated `Event` object that will release the thread to conduct processing.  You could then call `SetEvent` on the all of the threads' `Event` objects.  But how would you safely pass the COM object pointer (or more specifically, the `IAgileReference` pointer) to them?  'Cause there are no available parameters for a pre-instantiated thread.  Would you pass it to the C++ classes as a method parameter?  Or might you make it static/global, so any class/thread could access it, sort of like in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/marshaling-global-functions?view=msvc-160#atlmarshalptrinproc)?  And if so, would they `AddRef` it before use?  And would a mutex be necessary? Alternatively, you could use one of the `Ex` functions and call `QueueUserAPC`.  Or perhaps you could set up a single-thread threadpool for each class, and then maybe create an extended `OVERLAPPED` struct to send in to `PostQueuedCompletionStatus`, right?

There seem to be a lot of options, but I'm not sure which one is appropriate.  Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: Don't use WinApi calls for starting threads, use std::async (or std::thread) to start work on other threads.
Make sure that the apartment model on the background thread is set to MTA (::CoInitialize). AND do create ALL your COM objects on a thread that is initialized as MTA this ensures you can freely move the ATL::CComPtr's (don't use "naked" COM pointers) around between threads. You can start the threads with a lambda an capture the ATL::CComPtr's.

Comment: The question seems to have little to do with COM; you are mostly asking about how to pass units of work to a thread pool. This is usually done via a producer-consumer queue (before you ask, I don't believe one is provided in Windows API; you can find third-party implementations, or build your own out of a `std::queue`, a couple of mutexes and condition variables).

Comment: RoGetAgileReference will do AddRef (not only one, lots of AddRef...). The rest has nothing to do with COM.

Comment: You somehow got the threads to access the shared `Event`. You can use the same technique to get them to access the same `IAgileReference`.

Comment: It makes little sense to pass the interface pointer, all that does is ensure that threading won't be effective.  Dig out what you need from the IShellItem (like the path) and pass *that* to a worker thread.  So nothing is special anymore.

Comment: you can use `QueueUserWorkItem` for example. or `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` if you need self thread pool. but are exist sense work with `IFolderView2` from another thread ? all calls on interface will be marshaled and executed in original thread anyway. also you can use `CoMarshalInterface` and `CoUnmarshalInterface` too instead `IAgileReference`

Comment: @PepijnKramer - *Don't use WinApi calls for starting threads* - this is why ? :))

Answer (score 0):

> pass it as an argument (or otherwise make it available) to every
> thread in a group of waiting background threads

i strongly doubt that you want pass some object to **every** thread from pool. you need pass object/task to pool and any( arbitrary) thread from pool(group) will handle this. **single** arbitrary thread from group but not **every**

> Which WinApi thread functions are most suitable for setting up the
> background threads?

this is [`CreateThreadpool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-createthreadpool)

you can use it in next way

```
PTP_POOL CreateThreadpoolMinMax(ULONG cthrdMic, ULONG cthrdMost)
{
    if (PTP_POOL ptpp = CreateThreadpool(0))
    {
        if (SetThreadpoolThreadMinimum(ptpp, cthrdMic))
        {
            SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum(ptpp, cthrdMost);

            return ptpp;
        }

        CloseThreadpool(ptpp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> How should the COM object pointer get passed to them?

with `CreateThreadpoolWork` + `SubmitThreadpoolWork`

for example

```
BOOL PostWork(PTP_POOL ptp, IShellItemArray* psia)
{
    IStream* pStm;
    if (0 <= CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(__uuidof(psia), psia, &pStm))
    {
        TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON cbe;
        InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment(&cbe);
        SetThreadpoolCallbackPool(&cbe, ptp);

        if (PTP_WORK pwk = CreateThreadpoolWork(DoWork, pStm, &cbe))
        {
            SubmitThreadpoolWork(pwk);
            CloseThreadpoolWork(pwk);
            return TRUE;
        }

        if (0 <= CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(pStm, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psia)))
        {
            psia->Release();
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

as result your `DoWork` will be called

```
VOID NTAPI DoWork(
            _Inout_     PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE /*Instance*/,
            _Inout_opt_ PVOID                 pStm,
            _Inout_     PTP_WORK              /*pwk*/
            )
{
    ULONG_PTR pToken;
    HRESULT hr = CoGetContextToken(&pToken);

    if (hr == CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED )
    {
        hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED|COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    }

    IShellItemArray* psia;

    if (0 <= (hr = CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(reinterpret_cast<IStream*>(pStm), IID_PPV_ARGS(&psia))))
    {
        ULONG n;
        if (0 <= psia->GetCount(&n) && n)
        {
            do 
            {
                IShellItem* psi;

                if (0 <= psia->GetItemAt(--n, &psi))
                {
                    PWSTR psz;
                    if (0 <= psi->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEEDITING, &psz))
                    {
                        DbgPrint("<%S>\n", psz);
                        CoTaskMemFree(psz);
                    }
                    psi->Release();
                }
            } while (n);
        }

        psia->Release();
    }
}
```

possible (depend from your actual task and are you need dedicated thread pool, or short/fast tasks) and use system default pool. for example - post task

```
BOOL PostWork(IShellItemArray* psia)
{
    IStream* pStm;
    if (0 <= CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(__uuidof(psia), psia, &pStm))
    {
        if (QueueUserWorkItem(WorkCB, pStm, 0))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        if (0 <= CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(pStm, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psia)))
        {
            psia->Release();
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What if I need to make sure I pass the `IShellItemArray` to _each and every_ class/thread?  In other words, I have a group of consumer threads, and they each would like to know about the  `IShellItemArray`.  Will a threadpool still work for that? My impression was that a threadpool will queue the task and pass it to an available thread, but not each and every one.

Comment: @user15284017 - of course in case thread pool and my code - only single thread handle task. but i begin from - i doubt that you really need multiple thread handle this in parallel

Comment: So what is `pStm`'s reference count after calling `CoMarshalInterface`?  And after `CoReleaseMarshalData`? Is there a possibility it could get destroyed before the thread function accesses it?

Comment: @user15284017 - *Is there a possibility it could get destroyed before the thread function accesses it?* - strange question. of course no. CoMarshalInterface/CoReleaseMarshalData here unrelated at all. after `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` we have 1 reference to `pStm` and need once call `pStm->Release();` what i and do - or from `PostWork` if we fail post job to pool, or from `DoWork`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

#include <MsXml6.h>

// Helper class to match CoInitializes with CoUnitializes
class ComApartment 
{
public:
    ComApartment(DWORD dwInit)
    {
        HRESULT hr = ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, dwInit);  // S_OK = thread is initialized, S_FALSE thread was already initialized
        m_unitialize = (hr == S_OK);
        if (hr == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("COM initialization failed: thread already initialized to different model");
        }
    }

    virtual ~ComApartment()
    {
        if (m_unitialize)
        {
            ::CoUninitialize();
        }
    }

private:
    bool m_unitialize;
};

template <typename interface_t>
ATL::CComPtr<interface_t> CreateComObject(const UUID& clsid)
{
    ATL::CComPtr<interface_t> pItf;
    auto hr = pItf.CoCreateInstance(clsid, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) throw std::runtime_error("Could not create object");
    return pItf;
}

// Example on how to create COM Objects on background thread from main thread
template<typename interface_t>
auto CreateOnMTA(const CLSID& clsid)
{
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [clsid]
    {
        ComApartment appartment{ COINIT_MULTITHREADED };
        return CreateComObject<interface_t>(clsid);
    });

    return future.get();
}

template<typename lambda_t>
auto CallOnMTA(lambda_t lambda)
{
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [lambda]
    {
        ComApartment appartment{ COINIT_MULTITHREADED };
        return lambda();
    });

    // synchronize for now (this is just an example)
    return future.get();
}

int main()
{
    // keep at least on coinitialize alive for duration of program.
    ComApartment apartment{ COINIT_MULTITHREADED }; 

    auto pIObject = CreateOnMTA<IXMLDocument>(CLSID_XMLDocument);

    auto ver = CallOnMTA([pIObject]
    {
        ATL::CComBSTR version;
        pIObject->get_version(&version);
        return version;
    });

    std::wcout << ver << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create all threads MTA? One can need STA too. Also, on Windows std::async may get a thread from the thread pool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/future-functions?view=msvc-160#microsoft-specific) so you may mess up with threads you don't own.

Comment: I am well aware of the threadpool and take it into account. STA's have many more problems. You can't use com pointers from one STA in another so you can't pass them around freely, and they use a message queue with nasty reentrant behavior when handling events etc... The  threads havent been COM initialized and this code will leave them as they were CoUnitialize is called at the end. And the numbers CoInit/CoUninit will match, so this should be fine.

Comment: Being able to choose MTA vs STA is a COM feature, not a "problem".

Comment: I have 20+ years of experience with COM, and I've found that the STA model can be quite problematic. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272715/how-do-i-ensure-no-re-entrant-access-to-my-main-sta-com-server-c), windows message queues that got too full (extra latency etc.). We've long ago decided to move everything to MTA and background threads and handle all the multithreading stuff in C++.  Also doing it that way resulted in more responsive user interfaces (no delays on main message queue when making out-of-proc calls to another server etc.. etc..).

Comment: Basically the STA problem is that if "it" is making an "outgoing" COM call (A call to other apartment) it will start handling "Incoming" COM calls (events), and Window messages (if it is the mainthread). This means that code designed for a single thread suddenly can be called again (which is totally unexpected). And if that code wants to make another "outgoing" COM call it will lead to errors.